# Is it possible to display a joined query in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework application and I need to set the DataSource property of a BindingSource to the result of a joined query like so:

```
var joined = _context.Products.Join(_context.Categories, p=>p.CategoryId, c=>c.CategoryId, (product, category) => new
        {
            ProductName = product.Name,
            CategoryName = category.Name
        });
```

Is this possible or DataSources must equate to DbSet<>s?
For instance, this works:

```
this.supplierBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Suppliers.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Regards,
Juan

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to create a class for the results of the join and instantiate that as below:

```
    class ProductCategory
    {
        string ProductName { get; set; }
        string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

    private void test()
    {
        var joined = _context.Products.Join(_context.Categories, p => p.CategoryId, c => c.CategoryId, (product, category) => new ProductCategory
        {
            ProductName = product.Name,
            CategoryName = category.Name
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's just the first step. The problem is how can you set the DataSource property to a BindingList! So for example, adding the class you suggest allows us to create a DataSource (based on that class) but there is no way to bind that to a binding source or DataGridView because we cannot do this:          
this.productCategoryBindingSource.DataSource = joined.Local.ToBindingList();

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is:

```
var theList = joined.ToList();
var bindList = new BindingList<ProductCategory>(theList);
this.dataGridView4.DataSource = bindList;
```

This works!